# Some of DynamoDB item's attributes are nil

Tags: ios, swift, string, null, amazon-dynamodb

On my Swift-written iOS app, I have DynamoDB services connected.

On `HomeViewController` I'm scanning one the tables in my DynamoDB account, and I'm printing the results to check if it worked:

```
let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
scanExpression.filterExpression = "begins_with (id, :id)"
scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":id": GlobalVars.id]

GlobalVars.dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Item.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
    if let error = task.error as NSError? {
        print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
    } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
        for item in paginatedOutput.items as! [Item] {
            print("items", item)

            GlobalVars.items += [item]
            print("items array:", GlobalVars.items)
        }
        GlobalVars.numberOfItems = paginatedOutput.items.count
    }
    return ()
})
```

Every time in the `for-in` loop, it prints the item it got from the table. Each item has 7 attributes of itself, but when it is printing it, I see only 4 of the attributes. I see only the String attributes, without the 3 others (Float, Float, Boolean).

When I'm trying to get a Float attribute from one of the items I got in the scanning, I get `nil`.

It looks like it is able to get only strings, and nothing else.

In `TableViewController` on `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` I have this code which gets attributes from the item:

```
let item: Item = items[indexPath.row]

    let name: String = item.name!
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = name

    let priceFloat: Float = item.price!
    let price: String = priceFloat.description
    cell.itemPriceLabel.text = price
```

I'm able to get the `name` attribute which is String type, but I'm not able to get the `price` attribute which is Float type.

How can I fix this and get also the Float and Boolean attributes from the DynamoDB table using scanning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I used the different type for the price variable in `Item.swift` file.

Instead of:

```
var price: Float?
var booleanValue: Bool?
```

I was supposed to use:

```
var price: NSNumber?
var booleanValue: NSNumber?
```

On `Item.swift` file.